# PostgreSQL - Procedure does not exists

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a simple procedure that calls another procedure and I have an error in it:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: procedure public.tt_add_log(numeric, numeric) does not exist.

here is the code of the both procedures, one of the procedures "tt_merge" merges data from two table into third one, and one procedure is logging information "tt_add_log".

```
    create or replace procedure tt_merge (p_id numeric)
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare 
v_row public.tt_eod%rowtype;
v_data public.tt_data%rowtype;
 v_cur cursor for  select dt.id
      ,dt.status 
      ,dt.col1 
      ,te.status 
      ,te.col1
  from tt_data dt
      ,tt_eod te 
 where dt.id =te.id 
   and te.id = p_id;
--   
begin
--
    open v_cur;
fetch v_cur into v_row;
--
    insert into tt_final (id,numbero ,col1)
    values(v_row.id, v_row.status,v_row.col1);
--
update tt_eod
set status =1
where id =v_row.id;
call public.tt_add_log (v_row.id::numeric,v_row.status+1::numeric);
    close v_cur;
--
commit;
--
end;
$$
```

and this is the procedure for logging:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.tt_add_log(IN p_loglevel character varying, IN p_loginfo character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
begin 
    insert into public.tt_log (loglevel,loginfo)
    values(p_loglevel, p_loginfo);
end;
$procedure$
;
```

I've found similar problem here, but unfortunately adding ::datatypes didn't helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `public.tt_add_log(IN p_loglevel character varying, IN p_loginfo character varying)` vs `public.tt_add_log (v_row.id::numeric,v_row.status+1::numeric);` = `ERROR: procedure public.tt_add_log(numeric, numeric) does not exist.` The procedure signatures don't match.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, my real code is much more bigger so I have to look for the data type signatures, I will have same issue in my corporate code... 
I'll inform you about fix.

Thank you so much <3

Comment: In `psql` `\dfp public.*` is your friend. Change name pattern to suit.

Comment: I'm new in pg and \dfp public.*  was a news for me, it really helped.